# what is the correct way to use vector of vectors to create class buffer? or how to pass it correctly through functions?

Tags: c++, qt, class, qvector

I am writing a class to write a sync data from files to buffers. The buffer here is vector of vectors.
in the Header file when I tried

```
private:
QVector<QVector<int>> m_buffer(10); // I want to have an array of 10 vectors.
```

It failed to compile with the error:

```
 error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     QVector<QVector<int>> m_buffer(10);
                                    ^~
```

and the same error for the function when I tried in the header :

```
public:
void getDataFromFiles(QList<QString> audioFilesList, QVector<QVector<int> > buffer(10));
```

But it compiles when I just keep `void getDataFromFiles(QList<QString> audioFilesList, QVector<QVector<int> > buffer);`  for the function but in this case the buffers are not entered correctly as I want, I found that the data is the same for all 10 vectors.

the header:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void getDataFromFiles(QList<QString> audioFilesList, QVector<QVector<int> > buffer);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

//  QVector<QVector<int>> buffer(10); // this does not compile   

};
```

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QList<QString> audioFilesList;
    audioFilesList.append("/path/to/file1");
    audioFilesList.append("/path/to/file2");

    QVector<QVector<int>> buffer(10);

    getDataFromFiles(audioFilesList, buffer); // I think there is a way to pass buffer(10) instead?

}

void MainWindow::getDataFromFiles(QList<QString> audioFilesList, QVector<QVector<int> > buffer)
{
// ...
// to fill buffer I use 
buffer[i].append(value);

// ...
}
```

Comment: You can't initialize fields in field declaration by using parenthesis (since this is similar to member function declaration). Move initialization of `m_buffer` to constructor member initializer lists. Note that brace version will do something else (one element of value 10).

Comment: How about `std:array <QVector <int>, 10> m_buffer;`?

Comment: Also, braces work: `QVector <QVector <int>> m_buffer {10};`, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8DatCNS9ZJm7DMaE

Comment: @MarekR, u mean in the constructor do something like that `for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) { m_buffer[i] = new QVector<int> ; }`

Comment: @PaulSanders yes this is dangerous only for a vector of integer types. Still I think use of constructor member initializer lists is recommended.

Comment: @MarekR Yes, you're probably right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize if C++11 or higher:

```
QVector<QVector<int>> m_buffer=QVector<QVector<int>>(10);
```

Or in the constructor of m_buffer's class:

```
    QVector<QVector<int>> m_buffer;
    Constructor(): m_buffer(10){}
```

Best guess for this error is that compiler treats `m_buffer` as function with return type `QVector<QVector<int>>` as @Marek R mentioned.